# URL for my Protocol.HTTP never called by OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I have an OpenStreetMap (OSM) map with a vector layer fetching data from a Node.js server setup on my local machine on port 9000. The data is in GeoJSON format.

Here is the whole code:

```
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");

        var vectorFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        var vectorProtocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://localhost:9000/getcoords",
            format: vectorFormat,
            params: {
                "city":"PARIS",
                "city_code":3
            }
        });
        var refresh = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({ force: true, active: true });
        var vectorStrategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), refresh];

        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

        var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
            protocol: vectorProtocol,
            strategies: vectorStrategies,
            format: vectorFormat
        });

        map.addLayers([osm, vectors]);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.3983034, 47.078038).transform(fromProjection, toProjection), 6);
```

My problem is that my map is displayed, but the url defined in my protocol is never called. In firebug, I can't see any access to this url, so I can't see my vector layer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just found the problem : I forgot the parameter "name" in my Vector constructor... My bad